# Pass data to HTML page (ionic/angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need some help to pass rating value to the HTML page.

**Profile.page.ts**

```
logRatingChange(rating){
      //code to calculate avg rating

      rating = 4.5;
  }
```

**Profile.page.html**

```
<ionic4-star-rating #rating
                activeIcon = "ios-star"
                defaultIcon = "ios-star-outline"
                activeColor = "#488aff" 
                defaultColor = "#f4f4f4"
                halfStar = "true"
                readonly="false"
                rating= ""   <-----Passing the rating value here
                fontSize = "32px"
                (ratingChanged)="logRatingChange($event)">
</ionic4-star-rating>
```

I'm not sure how to pass the rating to the component in HTML page.
So sorry if this question is too noobish, since I can't find anything online related to this.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Angular data binding: https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax

The syntax is to either wrap the html attribute in square brackets `[propertyName]`:

```
<ionic4-star-rating #rating
                activeIcon = "ios-star"
                defaultIcon = "ios-star-outline"
                activeColor = "#488aff" 
                defaultColor = "#f4f4f4"
                halfStar = "true"
                readonly="false"
                [rating]= "rating"
                fontSize = "32px"
                (ratingChanged)="logRatingChange($event)">
</ionic4-star-rating>
```

**OR** you can use the template variable reference syntax: `{{varName}}`

```
<ionic4-star-rating #rating
                activeIcon = "ios-star"
                defaultIcon = "ios-star-outline"
                activeColor = "#488aff" 
                defaultColor = "#f4f4f4"
                halfStar = "true"
                readonly="false"
                rating= "{{rating}}"
                fontSize = "32px"
                (ratingChanged)="logRatingChange($event)">
</ionic4-star-rating>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rating` variable as Profile page class, you can use as

```
<ionic4-star-rating #rating
                activeIcon = "ios-star"
                defaultIcon = "ios-star-outline"
                activeColor = "#488aff" 
                defaultColor = "#f4f4f4"
                halfStar = "true"
                readonly="false"
                [rating]= "rating"
                fontSize = "32px"
                (ratingChanged)="logRatingChange($event)">
</ionic4-star-rating>
```